# Get highest values in array php

Tags: php

```
$array = array(
    10 => 6,
    12 => 7,
    13 => 7,
    14 => 4,
    15 => 6);
```

How to get the list of highest values in the above array? I need index 12 and 13
Any ideas?

Comment: "highest" is a superlative degree. How can the index 12 be qualified to be the highest index?

Comment: PHP has a [built-in function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) to extract the one element that has the highest value - you'll have to add some of your own logic in order to extract more than one if they are the same value. Why not try to implement this yourself and then come back with some more details if you are still having problems.

Comment: max($array); return the higher value in that array, but one value :)

Comment: $heigher = max($array);
 $heighVal = array();
 foreach ($array as $v) {
  
  if ( $v > $heigher || $v == $heigher ) {
   
   array_push($heighVal , $v);
  }
 }
 print_r($heighVal);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following code

```
$keys = array_keys($array, max($array));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($keys);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: array_keys($array, max($array)); returned list of keys having maximum values

Comment: so you want to get values also?

Comment: No. It works as expected. I need only all the keys having maximum values.

Comment: please tick correct to accept answer if helpful